# MariaDB on Centos7, service still called MySql

Tags: centos7, mariadb

I have a Centos 7 server.

Removed previous MariaDb 5.5 and installed MariaDb 10 following https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/

Added the MariaDB YUM Repository,and then executed:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

All good, then when I try to run:

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

I get:

```
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Yet if I run:

```
 sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Works and starts MariaDb. On a different server I can start MariaDb by calling it MariaDb not MySql as on this instance. I'm finding this a bit annoying. Have repeatedly removed MariaDb, rm -r /var/lib/mysql* but to no avail.

Server one works:

```
[root@phos bod]# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
[root@phos bod]# systemctl start mariadb.service
[root@phos bod]#
```

Server Two (same OS & same version of MariaDB) doesn't work:

```
[root@carpo bod]# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
[root@carpo bod]# systemctl start mariadb.service
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@carpo bod]# systemctl start mysql
[root@carpo bod]#
```

My question is: How can I manage the MariaDb service by it's correct name on Server Two?

Comment: Yes, this is a bit annoying, but what is your question?

Comment: Could you do `systemctl daemon-reload` before `systemctl start mariadb` and see if this helps?

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload` had not effect

Comment: If you stuck with the centos-packaged mariadb 5.5 you would get to call the service `mariadb`.  It is ironic that the packages from the MariaDB folks are less trademark-compliant than those from RH/CentOS, but if this is a problem for you maybe you should reconsider how badly you need mariadb 10.

Answer (score 5):

The name that MariaDB chose to give the service *is* `mysql`. If you want to see this changed, file a bug report with them and give them a very good argument.

Comment: You're unnecessarily abrasive. I refer to the documentation from MariaDb, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/ it is quite clear it can be started and stopped as mariaDb and I have this on another Centos instance.

Comment: That the documentation doesn't match reality would be a very good argument for your bug report. I'm sorry you feel that I was "unnecessarily abrasive". We just can't help you.

Comment: Documentation works correctly on other Centos instance.My understanding was this was a forum for all people to ask and answer questions. Rather than get abrupt response and attempt to close down a  discussion.

Comment: @GordonHickley `My understanding was this was a forum [...]` You are mistaken. This is not a forum.  `[...]  for all people to ask and answer questions` You are mistaken. This is a Q/A site for professionals to ask professional questions after a thorough study on the topic. `Rather than get abrupt response [...]` You did not get an abrupt response. You got an accurate response to your question. What more can you want?  `[...] and attempt to close down a discussion.` That's how ServerFault works. All Qs and As are subject to community input. Deal with it now (⌐■_■) and you'll be better later.

Comment: @Wesley If it is not a forum why did you get involved? The discussion was already effectively shutdown as 'refer a (non-existent) bug to developer'

Comment: @GordonHickley `If it is not a forum why did you get involved?`That question is a complete non sequitur. Wether it is or is not a forum has no bearing on why I got involved. `The discussion was already effectively shutdown as 'refer a (non-existent) bug to developer'` Yes, good. That was a perfectly acceptable response to the question. ServerFault is working as it's meant to. You have a great answer. Nothing else can be offered. Let's drink; _To knowledge, comrade!_

Comment: @Wesley "You did not get an abrupt response. You got an accurate response to your question. What more can you want?" The answer is factually incorrect and I maintain there is unnecessary abrasiveness and attempts to shoo away.